# write a command output to a file and match a string

Tags: perl

I am new to perl. I'm writing below script to print the system boot time information from the windows command "systeminfo". There look some problem here. I'm getting the output like this. Could someone help me.

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    my $filename = 'sysinfo.txt';
    my @cmdout = `systeminfo`;
    open(my $cmd, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
    print $cmd @cmdout;
    foreach my $file (@cmdout) {
        open my $cmd, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file or die;
        while (my $line = <$cmd>) {
            if ($line =~ m/.*System Boot.*/i) {
                print $line;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output: Died at perl_sysboottime.pl line 8.

Comment: What do you want to do by call `open my $cmd, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file`? Apparently the file won't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by the error printed, your script is dying the first time it executes

```
open my $cmd, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file or die;
```

This means that `open` failed to open a file.

I'm not familiar with Windows's commands, but I'll go by the example `systeminfo` output given [here](https://www.computerhope.com/systemin.htm).

After executing line 4, the array `@cmdout` contains the lines output by `systeminfo`. When line 8 is executed, `$file` has been set to the first line of the output, or `Host Name:                 COMPUTERHOPE\n` in my example (note the trailing newline). This is not a filename, so `open` fails.

It looks like you're trying to combine two different ways of iterating through the lines of a file, one inside of another. Try something like this:

```
foreach my $line (@cmdout) {
    if ($line =~ m/.*System Boot.*/i) {
        print $line;
    }
}
```